# White space records are retrieved despite having a check not include it?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select 'Total schools' As Title, Count(1) As Total_Count
From (Select Distinct School_Name, Indv_Id
      From D_Education D 
      where Regexp_Like(School_Name,'[^A-Za-z0-9, -./]+')
     );
```

this query is returning around 100 distinct school names.

Most of the records returned by this are having special characters like ?, \ or whitespace. My question is why is white space records are retreived despite having a check to exclude whitespace. Dorcas Place -  such records are coming.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression:

```
  where Regexp_Like(School_Name, '[^A-Za-z0-9, -./]+')
```

Is simply requiring that *at least one character not in your list* is in the name.

If you want names that have a special character, this may be what you want:

```
  where not Regexp_Like(School_Name, '^[A-Za-z0-9, -./]$')
```

This is checking that *all* characters in the name are valid.  The `^` and `$` are anchors in the regular expression.  They require that the entire string match the pattern.

Edit:

To allow single quotes, you would do:

```
  where not Regexp_Like(School_Name, '^[A-Za-z0-9, -./'']$')
```

You need to double the single quote, because it is the delimiter for a string.

Comment: Perfect @Gordon ! It helped a lot. Thanks! Could you please elaborate the difference in the above expressions?

Comment: One more quick question here, how do I add ' in ^[A-Za-z0-9, -./]$ so that name like O'Brien should not come in the list. When I am simply putting ' between [] it's showing me an error.

Comment: @Pushpendra, to escape a single quote `'` in Oracle, simply double it `''`. But you'll need a `+` or `*` before the `$` or the regex will match only one character.